# Отправить постом только имя файла

Tags: файлы, php

Есть ли возможность отправить постом только имя файла из `<input type="file" />` без самого файла? Мб, есть возможность реализовать не только средствами `PHP`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подключите к форме свой обработчик события "onsubmit" и обыграйте там вашу ситуацию...

Comment: Обработчик? А что это?

Comment: [Вот о чем-то таком](http://jsfiddle.net/j4VHR/) говорит тов. @gart67

Comment: Да, именно такой вариант я и имел ввиду...

Comment: Прошу прощения - я изначально не правильно подошел к вопросу (задался я им, когда увидел, что vk не обращает внимания на тип файла перед загрузкой), а сейчас уже не помню в чем, собственно, был затык :) Кстати, идея тов. woland`а будет, ИМХО, проще и лучше.

Comment: Самое главное что Вы поняли что и как можно сделать :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно  [так еще](http://jsfiddle.net/T58fg/1/)